# Signing Nvidia drivers for Secure Boot - Nvidia module location

Tags: nvidia, proprietary-drivers, secure-boot, signature

I want to sign my nvidia driver so I can use it with Secure Boot.
I'm trying to follow these instructions for nvidia driver:
https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot#Using_your_key_to_sign_modules_.28Traditional_Way.29

I already have MOK keys.
I've installed nvidia drivers with apt-get install nvidia-driver. Now I'm signing it.
I can't find location of my nvidia module.

ChatGPT has suggested something like that:

```
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 /path/to/MOK.priv /path/to/MOK.der $(modinfo -n nvidia)
```

But I'm getting error (even with modinfo  -n nvidia)

```
sudo /sbin/modinfo nvidia
modinfo: ERROR: Module nvidia not found
```

I've also tried it, but got no output:

```
sudo find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name "nvidia.ko"
```

What should I do to find my nvidia driver?  It should be  there if I have installed a package, right?

Answer (score 0):

As you have installed your drivers using apt, you should not follow these instructions but instead the next paragraph : https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot#Making_DKMS_modules_signing_by_DKMS_signing_key_usable_with_the_secure_boot

I just had the same need as you and it went smoothly, just a simple reboot

Comment: Will try that. Now I have to sign drivers every time I get new kernel version

Comment: my nvidia drivers installed by apt seem to not be signed..
When running modinfo there are no `sig_id`, `signer`, `sig_key`, `sig_hashalgo` and `signature`.
They should be signed before after installing without any my actions. right?

Comment: Do you have some ideas what else could I do? Right now every kernel/drivers update forces me to sign drivers manually.